# Windows 7 Remote Desktop Services

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a desktop with win 7 ultimate and a laptop with win 2000 pro.
Is it possible for me to log in to my desktop from the laptop without kicking out the user that's currently on the desktop?
I want to have a separate session.

TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You need a server OS for this.

BUT.... I found this (untested but looks promising)...

http://www.blogsdna.com/2336/enable-multiple-user-accessconcurrent-user-sessions-for-remote-desktop-on-windows-7.htm

Comment: FYI, that tool only works on a specific build of Win7. It didn't work for me, but knowing what to Google for (thanks!) led me to a [Universal Termsrv.dll Patch](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/windows-guides/1879-enable-concurrent-sessions-windows-7-windows-vista-windows-xp-termsrv-dll.html), which worked beautifully. Just leaving a note here for future folks doing the same search as I did.

Comment: @mud - you should add that as a separate answer with a quick breakdown of how it works. also note this is technically against licensing but if you're a developer especially if you have MSDN then perhaps you're ok